# DirectInput C++, Steering Wheel and DIVIRTUAL_DRIVING_RACE Access

Tags: c++, joystick, directinput

I'm new to direct input. I managed to initialize my Steering Wheel as a `DI8DEVCLASS_GAMECTRL` device and get all data. Now pedals are a bit of a pain, since they share one axis (accelerate is doing the Y-Axis positive and brake is doing negative Y-Axis values, means if both are pressed the value is 0)

How do i access the below values in a nice fashion via `DirectInput`?

- `DIAXIS_DRIVINGR_STEER`
- `DIAXIS_DRIVINGR_ACCELERATE`
- `DIAXIS_DRIVINGR_BRAKE`